# Why does Parallel.Invoke fail to complete all the actions?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I worked on an example in the text book about parallel programming in C#. The book suggests Parallel.Invoke can replace the creation, invocation and waiting of tasks. However, I tried and found that if I use Parallel.Invoke, the tasks wouldn't finish before returning a value. But in theory, Parallel.Invoke should always wait.

The code:

```
    private byte[] getDataForGraph(int dataSize)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[dataSize];


        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generateGraphData(data, 0, pixelWidth / 8)),
            () => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth / 8,
                pixelWidth / 4)),
            () => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth / 4,
                pixelWidth * 3 / 8)),
            () => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth * 3 / 8,
                pixelWidth / 2)));

        return data;
    }
```

And the way to execute the function:

```
Task<byte[]> getDataTask = Task<byte[]>.Factory.StartNew(() => getDataForGraph(dataSize));
byte[] data = getDataTask.Result;
```

The `private void generateGraphData(byte[] data, int partitionStart, int partitionEnd)` is a function that fills the data array, from partitionStart to partitionEnd.

If I run the program, only part of the array is filled.
But if I replace the Invoke with

```
Task first = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generateGraphData(data, 0, pixelWidth / 8));
Task second = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth / 8, pixelWidth / 4));
Task third = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth / 4, pixelWidth * 3 / 8));
Task fourth = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth * 3 / 8, pixelWidth / 2));
Task.WaitAll(first, second, third, fourth);
```

The program runs as expected (the array is fully filled).

What may be the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It performs the *actions* until they are complete. In your case, each action is to call `Task.Factory.StartNew(...)` - and **that** has completed; however, there is no guarantee that each of thses **tasks** has been queued/processed yet. The difference is the `WaitAll` (which you haven't called in your `Parallel` example).

One option here would be to reduce this to:

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => generateGraphData(data, 0, pixelWidth / 8),
    () => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth / 8, pixelWidth / 4),
    () => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth / 4, pixelWidth * 3 / 8),
    () => generateGraphData(data, pixelWidth * 3 / 8, pixelWidth / 2)
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. I just copied the code, and didn't check it carefully.